# Mongodb Aggregation Pipeline limit $lookup fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections that i am trying to aggregate together to produce the below desired output but am struggling with how to limit the fields in the array returned by the lookup.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
project
{
    _id: ObjectId("ABC")    
    projectName: "Project One"
}

user
{
    _id: ObjectId("...")
    email: "test1@test.co.uk",
    firstname: "Test1",
    lastname: "Record",
    project: [{projectId: ObjectId("ABC")}]
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("...")
    email: "test2@test.co.uk",
    firstname: "Test2",
    lastname: "Record",
    project: [{projectId: ObjectId("ABC")}, {projectId: ObjectId("DEF")}]
}
```

desired output

```
{
    projectName: "Project One"
    userDetail: [{firstname: "Test1",lastname: "Record"}, 
            {firstname: "Test2",lastname: "Record"}]        
}
```

current workings

```
db.project.aggregate([{$match: {_id: ObjectId("ABC")}} 
,  {$lookup: {
                from: "user",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "project.projectId",
                as: "userDetail"
            }
} 
, {$project: {_id: 1, projectName: 1}}
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to map the fields of your choice in [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

```
{
  "$project":{
    "projectName":1,
    "userDetail":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$userDetail",
        "as":"ud",
        "in":{
          "firstname":"$$ud.firstname",
          "lastname":"$$ud.lastname"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.project.aggregate([{$match: {_id: ObjectId("ABC"),}} , 
{$lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "project.projectid",
            as: "userDetail"
        }
}, {$project: {_id: 1, projectName:1,"userDetail.firstname":1,"userDetail.lastname":1}}
]).pretty()
```